# Convert TensorFlow tensor of variable size to std::vector in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a given C++ `tensorflow::Tensor` (variable shape) object.

I would like to convert it to a `std::vector` (nested vectors, in case of multi-dimensional vector).

Is there a clean way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this vector? Do you know how many dimension the tensor has? Otherwise, you can't even name the type of the vector without using some kind of polymorphism, which would complicate everything.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no.

You could create a `vector<boost::any>`, and nest those, but the code consuming that is going to be messy.

If you know at compile time what shapes you are operation on, you could use something like

```
temlate<size_t N, typename T>
struct tensor_traits {
    using type = std::vector<tensor_traits<N-1, T>::type>;
}

template<typename T>
struct tensor_traits<0, T> {
    using type = T;
}

template<size_t N, typename T>
tensor_traits<N, T>::type toVector(const tensorflow::Tensor & input)
{
    assert(/* shape and type match */);
    tensor_traits<N, T>::type result;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < input.dim_size(0); ++i)
    {
        result.push_back(toVector<N-1, T>(input[i])); 
        // Or however you get a smaller Tensor from a larger one. The documentation is unclear
    }
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
T toVector<0, T>(const T & input)
{
    return input; 
    // Base case of single value
}
```

Comment: Well, I need to plug the tensor into another code which works with std nested vectors... If I have a simple iterator, then I need to know the dimensionality a-priori to maintain the dimensions I presume.

Comment: Do you have functions like `void doStuff(vector<vector<vector<int>>> & input)` ? You *can* make a function that converts tensors of a specific shape to vectors of that shape, but that isn't general

Comment: Yes, you are right. For the iterator, `for (auto it = std::begin(Y_pred); it!=std::end(Y_pred); ++it) { ... }` does not work for me. `Y_pred` is a tensorflow tensor.